# How to construct web and mobile front ends for Restful app (Mid 2018)

Tags: javascript, web, mobile

I have put together a simple set of Restful APIs to support an application which I am developing. (Using Java, Maven, Spring & Docker conceptually similar to this simple tutorial [Spring Restful Tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/))

Now I want to setup the foundations of my front end(s) {Mobile and Web}, but I am not sure which technology to adopt, hence this question: **"How to construct web and mobile front ends for Restful app."** I have included Mid-2018 because I know that technology moves very quickly.

To make this more specific, I have a few requirements I would like to meet:

1. The development framework & tools should be no/low cost.
2. Minimize the learning curve for new technologies.
3. The Web Front End must be built as a docker image.
4. Ideally the Web Front End would be a Spring Boot Project.
5. The mobile Front End(s) should support a wide range of platforms (if not all)
6. The Mobile Front End(s) should be small, ready to deploy to a user's phone.
7. Code should be reused between these front ends as much as possible.

If anyone can point me to a tutorial or working example of their suggested technology solution then that would be fantastic !

Comment: [For `REST` you need `HATEOAS`-](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/)

Comment: Hi @AJAX, thank you for your suggestion. Yes, my Restful API uses Spring HATEOAS to include related links. But I want a user friendly front end too.

Comment: What do you mean by `front-end`? `Hypermedia` is the simplest `front-end`. You cannot change it. Style `links`.

Comment: Well, I was considering Angular or React, but I wanted to leave it open ended and watch for replies. Your recommendation (if I understand correctly) is that I can just apply a bit of styling to the Restful responses (plus links) and my app will be near complete. Can you point me in the direction of an app where this has been done ? Thank you

Comment: [Check this Stackoverflow-link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139095/actual-examples-for-hateoas-rest-architecture)

Comment: [Also a good book.](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529260.do) Recommended by Roy Fielding.